# Hi, It is related to the batch jobs, while running the job, I am getting the below error

Tags: apex, batch

Exception caught: Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0016900002e5Ka0AAE; first error: MERGE_FAILED, These accounts have the same related contact. Open the related contact record and remove redundant account–contact relationships. Then try merging again.

Exception caught: Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0016900002e5Ka0AAE; first error: MERGE_FAILED, These accounts have the same related contact. Open the related contact record and remove redundant account–contact relationships. Then try merging again.

I have the below code:

```
public class APB014_AccountMerge implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
    
    //public Integer numResults; 
    //public Integer counter=Integer.valueOf(System.Label.counter);
    
        public APB014_AccountMerge(){
            //numResults = 0;
        }
    
        public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    
            System.debug('## APB014_AccountMerge START');
            
            String query = 'select id, Status__c, MergeResult__c, MasterCustomer__r.Id, SlaveCustomer__r.Id, MasterCustomer__r.ispersonaccount, MasterCustomer__r.personcontactid, MasterCustomer__r.RecordTypeId,'
                + ' SlaveCustomer__r.OwnerId from CustomerMergeEntry__c '
                + 'where Status__c = \'0\' and MasterCustomer__c != null and SlaveCustomer__c != null '
                + 'ORDER BY MasterCustomer__c, SlaveCustomer__r.LastModifiedDate';
    
            //  -> Include a Limit for testing in order to be able to Launch a bulk Batch
            if(Test.isRunningTest()) query += ' LIMIT 200'; 
    
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    
        }
    
        public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<CustomerMergeEntry__c> scope){
            // Match & Merge - errors Exception Caught 
            UserByPass__c bypassUserConfig = UserByPass__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getUserId());
            bypassUserConfig.ValidationRules__c = true;
            bypassUserConfig.SetupOwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            upsert bypassUserConfig;
    
            /*if (numResults == 0){
                numResults = scope.size();
            }
    
            if (numResults <= counter){            */
    
                System.debug('## APB014_AccountMerge EXECUTE');
    
                Database.MergeResult result;
                List<id> masterIds = new List<id>();
                Set<Id> masterIdsB2C = new Set<Id>();
                List<id> slaveIds = new List<id>();
                List<CustomerMergeEntry__c>   = new List<CustomerMergeEntry__c>();
                Map<Id, Id> mapSlaveMaster = new Map<Id, Id>();
                Set<Id> accountsOtherThanB2B = new Set<Id>();
                Map<Id,Id> mapMasterLastSlave = new Map<Id,Id>();
                Set<Id> setIds = new Set<Id>();
                for(CustomerMergeEntry__c cme : scope){
                    //**BEGIN** change lookup from AccountExternalRef to Account
                    masterIds.add(cme.MasterCustomer__c);
                    slaveIds.add(cme.SlaveCustomer__c);
                    setIds.add(cme.SlaveCustomer__c);
                    setIds.add(cme.MasterCustomer__c);
                    mapSlaveMaster.put(cme.SlaveCustomer__c, cme.MasterCustomer__c);
                    mapMasterLastSlave.put(cme.MasterCustomer__c,cme.SlaveCustomer__c);
                    //**END** change lookup from AccountExternalRef to Account
                }
                
                Set<AccountShare> slaveSharing = new Set<AccountShare>([Select Id, AccountId, AccountAccessLevel, ContactAccessLevel, 
                CaseAccessLevel, OpportunityAccessLevel, UserOrGroupId from AccountShare where AccountId in: slaveIds AND RowCause = 'Manual']);   
                MergeUtils.checkDynamicMergeFields(mapMasterLastSlave,'Account', setIds);
                deleteDoubledAssetRelations(masterIds, slaveIds, scope);
                         
                for(CustomerMergeEntry__c cme : scope){
                    try{
                        //**BEGIN** change lookup from AccountExternalRef to Account
                        result = Database.merge(new Account(Id=cme.MasterCustomer__c), cme.SlaveCustomer__c); //Modified by Gaurav as part of C1STAGILE-23471
                           
                        //**END** change lookup from AccountExternalRef to Account
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        cme.MergeResult__c = 'Exception caught: ' + e.getMessage();
                        cme.Status__c = '3';
                    }
                    if(result != null && result.isSuccess()){
                        cme.Status__c = '2';
                        //**BEGIN** change lookup from AccountExternalRef to Account
                        if(cme.MasterCustomer__r.ispersonaccount){
                            masterIdsB2C.add(cme.MasterCustomer__r.personcontactid);
                        }
                        if (cme.MasterCustomer__r.RecordTypeId != AccountConstants.ACCOUNT_RT_B2B) {
                            accountsOtherThanB2B.add(cme.MasterCustomer__c);
                        }
                        //**END** change lookup from AccountExternalRef to Account
                        /* Slave Customer is deleted after merge the accounts so we need 
                        cleaning the field to prevent an error */
                        cme.SlaveCustomer__c = null;
                    }
                    mergeResults.add(cme);
                }
                update mergeResults;            
    
                /*  -> Insert Back the visibility lost after merging to the Slave Account */
    
                Set<AccountShare> newAccountSharing = new Set<AccountShare>();
    
                for (AccountShare acsh: slaveSharing){
                    Id masterId = mapSlaveMaster.get(acsh.AccountId);
                    if (accountsOtherThanB2B.contains(masterId)) {
                        AccountShare newAcsh = new AccountShare(
                                AccountId = masterId,
                                RowCause = Schema.AccountShare.RowCause.Manual,
                                AccountAccessLevel = acsh.AccountAccessLevel,
                                CaseAccessLevel = acsh.CaseAccessLevel,
                                OpportunityAccessLevel = acsh.OpportunityAccessLevel,
                                UserOrGroupId = acsh.UserOrGroupId
                        );
                        if (masterIdsB2C.contains(masterId)) {
                            newAcsh.ContactAccessLevel = Constants.CONTACT_ACCESS_LEVEL_EDIT;
                        }
                        newAccountSharing.add(newAcsh);
                    }
                }
                
                // Generate the list of AccountShare to late create the account sharing. It is needed a List as collection instead of a Set.
                List<AccountShare> toInsert = new List<AccountShare>(newAccountSharing);
    
                Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(toInsert,false);
                
                for (Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
                    if (!sr.isSuccess()) {             
                        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                            System.debug('## APB014 : The following error has occurred. -> ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());                    
                        }
                    }
                }
                /*  */
                MergeUtils.checkContactabilityRecords(masterIdsB2C);
            //}
            // Match & Merge - errors Exception Caught 
            bypassUserConfig.ValidationRules__c = false;
            update bypassUserConfig;
        }   
    
        public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
    
            System.debug('## APB014_AccountMerge FINISH');
            
            /*if(numResults>counter){
                Database.executeBatch(new APB014_AccountMerge(),counter);
            }*/
    
        }
        /*  Name        : deleteDoubledAssetRelations
            Description : Delete asset relations related to slave Accounts that would be doubling already existing relations to master Account. 
            @PARAM      : masterIds, slaveIds --> Account IDs for quering all Accont Asset relations. 
                        : mergeEntries --> List of objects linking marged master and slave records. 
            @OUTPUT     : void --> All duplicating relations are deleted. 
        */
        private void deleteDoubledAssetRelations(List<Id> masterIds, List<Id> slaveIds, List<CustomerMergeEntry__c> mergeEntries){
            Map<Id,Map<String,AccountContactAssetRelation__c>> relationsByAccountIds = new Map<Id, Map<String, AccountContactAssetRelation__c>>();
            List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
            accountIds.addAll(masterIds);
            accountIds.addAll(slaveIds);
            
            
            for(Account relation: [SELECT Id,(Select id, AccountRole__c, AccountId__c, AssetId__c from Account_Contact_Asset_Relations__r) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]){
                for(AccountContactAssetRelation__c ac:relation.Account_Contact_Asset_Relations__r){
                    if(!relationsByAccountIds.containsKey(ac.AccountId__c)){
                        relationsByAccountIds.put(ac.AccountId__c, new Map<String, AccountContactAssetRelation__c>());
                    }
                    
                    relationsByAccountIds.get(ac.AccountId__c).put(ac.AssetId__c + '_' + ac.AccountRole__c,ac);
                }
            }
            
           
    
            List<AccountContactAssetRelation__c> doublingRelations = new List<AccountContactAssetRelation__c>();
            for(CustomerMergeEntry__c mergeEntry: mergeEntries){
                Map<String, AccountContactAssetRelation__c> slaveRelations = relationsByAccountIds.get(mergeEntry.SlaveCustomer__c);
                Map<String, AccountContactAssetRelation__c> masterRelations = relationsByAccountIds.get(mergeEntry.MasterCustomer__c);
    
                if(slaveRelations != null && masterRelations != null){
    
                    for(String assetAccountRoleKey: slaveRelations.keySet()){
                        if(masterRelations.containsKey(assetAccountRoleKey)){
                            doublingRelations.add(slaveRelations.get(assetAccountRoleKey));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
            System.debug('DELETED ASSET RELATIONS -> ' + doublingRelations);
            if(!doublingRelations.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    delete doublingRelations;
                } catch(Exception ex){
                    System.debug('## APB014 : The following error has occurred deleteing AccountAssetRelations. -> ' + ex.getMessage());    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you'll need to query the [AccountContactRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_accountcontactrelation.htm) table and remove any duplicates you find there.

```
// From your original code
for(CustomerMergeEntry__c cme : scope){
  masterIds.add(cme.MasterCustomer__c);
  slaveIds.add(cme.SlaveCustomer__c);
  setIds.add(cme.SlaveCustomer__c);
  setIds.add(cme.MasterCustomer__c);
  mapSlaveMaster.put(cme.SlaveCustomer__c, cme.MasterCustomer__c);
  mapMasterLastSlave.put(cme.MasterCustomer__c,cme.SlaveCustomer__c);
}
// New code--let's delete any duplicate relationships
AccountContactRelation[] duplicateRelations = new AccountContactRelation[0];
Set<AccountContactRelation> existingRelations = new Set<AccountContactRelation>();
for(AccountContactRelation relation: [SELECT ContactId, AccountId FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE AccountId = :setIds]) {
  // Set.add returns false if the set was not modified.
  // This means the item was a duplicate.
  if(!existingRelations.add(new AccountContactRelation(ContactId=relation.ContactId, AccountId=relation.AccountId)) {
    duplicateRelations.add(relation);
  }
}
delete duplicateRelations;
```

You may need to add extra logic if you're concerned about failures, since you wouldn't want to delete a relationship that you find out later you didn't need.